# jQuery move table row <tr> to next <tr> with class assigned

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table of tasks as so:

```
<table>
<tr class="open">
<td>Some task 1</td>
</tr>
<tr class="open">
<td>Some task 2</td>
</tr>
<tr class="open">
<td>Some task 3</td>
</tr>
<tr class="closed">
<td>Some task 4</td>
</tr>
<tr class="closed>
<td>Some task 5</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

The tasks are listed by open then closed. When I mark a task as closed, I want to move that row to above the first closed task. For example, if I set 'Some task 1' as closed, I want to move the row to above 'some task 4', beneath the other open tasks.

What's the best way to do this?

I've tried using .closest() but this doesn't seem to work with class selectors.

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: The best way is to do it on your own so that you can learn as you figure out the task.

Comment: Sorry, I should have added what I've tried. I haven't just come here expecting someone else to do my work, but I generally didn't know the best way to go about it. As it turns out, the answers below are far more elegant than what I had.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `$tr` is your row to be moved:

```
$('tr.open').last().after($tr);
```

or as one line including the class updates:

```
$tr.insertAfter('tr.open:last').removeClass('open').addClass('closed');
```

Answer (score 1):

if its possible for there to be no closed:

```
function onClosed($newlyClosedElement){
    if ($('.closed').length){
         $newlyClosedElement.insertBefore($('.closed').first());
    }
    else{
         $newlyClosedElement.insertAfter($('.open').last());
    }

    $newlyClosedElement.removeClass('open').addClass('closed');
}
```

Comment: @izip why use this when the `.last().after()` version in my answer doesn't need the test?